# regex operator giving error operator does not exist: bigint ~ unknown

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am very new to postgres and trying to find out an issue with the query using a regex.

Query:

```
select name, ip_address, install_status 
from sn_cache_prod.cmdb_ci 
where support_group = 'bee96a2135a631007fa2c5751b2c74be'
and u_environment = 5 
and install_status ~ '(110|3)';
```

Error:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: bigint ~ unknown
```

`install_status` column is defined as `bigint`.

Can the query work without casting?

Comment: What are you trying to do ? Are you trying to match a regular expression on this integer  ? Why not just `install_status=110 or install_status=3` ?

Answer (score 1):

A regular expressions applies to string (text) values, it can't be used on numbers. In your case you want the `IN` operator:

```
select name,ip_address,install_status 
from sn_cache_prod.cmdb_ci 
where support_group = 'bee96a2135a631007fa2c5751b2c74be'
  and u_environment = 5 
  and install_status in (110,3);
```

That's equivalent to

```
and (install_status = 110 or install_status = 3)
```

Comment: Thanks that helps.